# How can i pause or make the progress bar visible false in Android such that it should appear only when clicked?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-layout

I have a login form in Android and i want when i do it login a progressBar circular icon appears of loading and then it should be hidden when next Intent is opened.
I have made it visible false once the new intent is opened, but that icon does not appear when i click the login button, the code executes so fastly that it hides my progressbar, even the code of visibility false is after the new intent object creation, but its not working,
let me know how to handle progress bar in this case.

Thanks in advance
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are aware that to show progress you will need asnyTask or handler with a separate thread . in case you are using ASncTask showProgressBar in onPreExecute . sleep for a particular time in DoinBackground as you don't have to do anything but need to show loading , now in onPostExecute hide progressBar and move to next screen .

if you are using handler go through same approach .

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button...

```
pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

When you're going to call the new intent...

```
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If that's not what you're looking for, we'll need some code and a better description.  I'm a little lost.